# How to use aggregate function if we need aggregate of specific rows in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following code which has 7 rows. I would like to take avg, min, max of the product name column that are same (for example: I have 3 products with a name of 'Shoes' that are same and their costs are 50, 45, 60. I have one product named 'Hat' with a cost of 50. Now I would like to take average of 3 common rows i.e 50, 45, 60 and it should display 51.66. For the other row, it should display 50 and so forth)

My problem is if I run below query it display the avg, max, min of same row instead of taking avg, min, max of rows that are same.

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT.ProductName,
    Vendor.VendorName, VendorProduct.Cost,
    AVG(COST) AS AVG, 
    MIN(COST) AS MIN,
    MAX(COST) AS MAX
FROM
    PRODUCT
JOIN
    VendorProduct ON VendorProduct.ProductID = PRODUCT.ProductID
JOIN
    Vendor ON Vendor.VendorID = VendorProduct.VendorID
GROUP BY
    PRODUCT.ProductName, VendorProduct.Cost, Vendor.VendorName
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please decide if your question is about MySQL or sqlserver, the answers are quite different depending

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT p.ProductName,
       AVG(vp.COST) AS AVG, MIN(vp.COST) AS MIN, MAX(vp.COST) AS MAX
FROM PRODUCT p join
     VendorProduct vp
     on vp.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductName;
```

Notes:

- I have qualified all the column names using abbreviations for the table.
- I removed the vendor name from the `SELECT`, because you want the averages by product.
- I removed the vendor name and price from the `GROUP BY` for the same reason.
- `AVG`, `MIN`, and `MAX` are bad names for columns, because these are SQL keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
AVG(cost) as avg
```

To

```
AVG(cost) OVER(PARTITION BY productname) as [avg]
```

Make the same change (adding an OVER clause) to the other aggregates 
and also remove the GROUP BY line entirely

This will give you the same number of rows as you're getting now, but the aggregates will repeat for every identical value of product name. You also get to keep the vendor details

What is it? In sqls it's called a window function; a way of grouping a data set and implicitly connecting the grouped results to the detail rows, without losing the detail rows' detail. MSDN will have a lot to say about them if your curiosity is piqued

Note, Gordon's advice re column naming